# MySQL text grouping

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have the following table:

```
id    | state | type | my_text
--------------------------------------
12345 | OH    | 01   | blah
12345 | OH    | 01   | testing
12345 | OH    | 01   | hello world
12345 | OH    | 02   | something else
12345 | OH    | 02   | more text
```

Does there exist a MySQL grouping function that would allow me to output something like this?:

```
id    | state | type | my_text
--------------------------------------
12345 | OH    | 01   | blah|testing|hello world
12345 | OH    | 02   | something else|more text
```

I am aware of similar functions for working with numbers (i.e. to calculate the average of a bunch of grouped rows), but I am looking for something that will group together text fields and delimit them. It seems fairly straight-forward, but I cannot seem to find the appropriate way to do this.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` can do this, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

```
SELECT id, state, type, GROUP_CONCAT(my_text SEPARATOR '|')
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id, state, type
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for and a very quick response. SO is not letting select the answer as "correct" for another 4 minutes.

Comment: In the meantime, I'm now wondering how I could make something like this:
id    | state | type | my_text_01 | my_text_02
--------------------------------------------------------------
12345 | OH    | 01   | blah|testing|hello world | something else|more text

Comment: Hrm, that didn't format well, but basically, I would like to combine the two lines of the output for types 01 and 02, into two distinct my_text fields named my_text_01 and my_text_02.

Comment: I'm not really sure how you should do that, but I'm pretty sure something like that is already asked on SO